# Symfony: How to inject a form to create/edit an entity

Tags: php, symfony

In a very simple controller that only retrieves POST info and creates a new entity I'd like to replace this:

The constructor of the controller:

```
public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        FormFactoryInterface $formFactory,
        EntityFactoryInterface $authorImageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->authorImageFactory = $authorImageFactory;
    }
```

Now, this works perfectly fine. But instead of injecting the formFactory I'd like to inject directly the form. The problem is I don't know how to tell the form to manage the entity I just created.

The action:

```
public function uploadAction(
    Request $request
) {
    $authorImage = $this->authorImageFactory->create();
    $authorImage->setAuthor($author);
    $form = $this->formFactory->create('AppBundle\Form\Type\AuthorImageType', $authorImage);
```

Comment: I would think $form->setData would work.  If not then make your own EntityFormFactoryInterface which would hide the AuthorImageType dependency from your controller.